# Magento 2 - where is method declaration of $this->getAddress() in Magento\Directory\Helper\Data line146

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, dependency-injection, dependency

where is method declaration of $this->getAddress() in 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data.php#L146

```
public function getRegionCollection()
{
    if (!$this->_regionCollection) {
        $this->_regionCollection = $this->_regCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->_regionCollection->addCountryFilter($this->getAddress()->getCountryId())->load();
    }
    return $this->_regionCollection;
}
```

i don't know where is method come from, but if i search "function getAddress()", 
i fount it in Magento\module-customer\Block\Address\Edit
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php#L211

```
/**
 * Return the associated address.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->_address;
}
```

i don't think that class is related

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist. Since it is not derived from the [Data Object](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php) class there are also no magic methods available here.

The only reason this is not raising an error seems to be that this method is not used anywhere: https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getRegionCollection